# Hardcoded Address

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I did an audit on a smart contract and it says it has a hardcoded address.

```
constructor() public {
        symbol = "0PUCKS";
        name = "0 Pucks Token";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
        balances[**0x5A86f0cafD4ef3ba4f0344C138afcC84bd1ED222**] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), **0x5A86f0cafD4ef3ba4f0344C138afcC84bd1ED222**, _totalSupply);
```

Is the bold address considered the hardcoded address?  Or is there a different one?

Comment: Do you see any other address in this code???

Comment: Not that I can see.    I was just trying to make sure there could not be anohter type of hardcoded address.  Thx